# Support vs smallest closed subset with probability $1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ denote a metric space and $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$.

I thought that the support of $\mu$ was defined as the smallest closed subset $A$ such that $\mu(A)=1$. However, upon checking Wikipedia I see that [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition) is more complicated and involves open subsets of $X$.

Is there a less general setting in which the support of $\mu$ coincides with the smallest closed subset $A$ such that $\mu(A)=1$ ?

Comment: Note in general there does not have to *exist* a smallest closed subset of measure 1.  Counterexamples include things like a [measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal) equipped with a discrete metric.  Every set is closed, and there are no point masses.  So given any closed set of measure 1, you can delete one point and have a smaller closed set of measure 1.  If you intersect all the closed sets of measure 1, you get $\emptyset$ whose measure is 0.

Comment: Why did you delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785169/minimize-sum-j-1n-p-j1-p-jq-2-under-the-constraint-sum-j-1n-p) recently? Anything wrong?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, I made an important mistake with respect to my work: I need to maximize the objective (not minimize as stated in the question).

Comment: @Marloumarlou OK. Thanks. It is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An assumption on $\mu$ where you can guarantee that $C$ exists is that if $O_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A$ are open sets and $\mu(O_{\alpha}) = 0$ for all $\alpha$, then $\mu(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}O_{\alpha}) = 0$. In this setting, you let $C^c$ be the union of all open sets $O$ with $\mu(O) = 0$.

This assumption on $\mu$ holds if $(X, d)$ is second-countable (equivalent to separability).